# Mangeto url change slash to hyphen

Tags: url-rewrite

i want change category and subcategory url level instead of slash change hyphen. please help me

**current url:**

books/books/philosophy.html

**want to change like**

books-books-philosophy.html

Answer (score 0):

Go admin side on top menu `Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management`

And search books/books/philosophy.html in `Request Path` field and click edit button and replace Request Path from `books/books/philosophy.html` to `books-books- philosophy.html` after save and check frontend.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello abdul, I have tried this one not working. i want change dynamically for all category and sub category url's